# Assign already assigned excel cell format to a cell insert with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a partly encrypted excel sheet in my hands in that i want to insert certain values with xlwings on python. Its working great but:

How can I format a cell inserted with xlwings to have the same format as the default excel sheet?

Please see the picture. In both rows i enter date by 03.03.2022
But in row 8 entered with xlwings and row 9 entered by hand and pressed enter.

```
#Code for row 8
sheet.range('B8').value = "02.03.2022"
```

[image]

However, when i click on the xlwings row 8 and press enter, it will change to the correct format like row 9.

Is there a way that the row can automatically adapt the correct format from the excel sheet?

Comment: Use `number_format` such as `sheet.range('B8').number_format = "General"` to specify the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution in:

```
sheet.range('B8').value = dt.datetime(2022,3,2)
```

Which then formated the date correctly!